# cant display rows from belongsToMany

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I cant display any rows from a belongsToMany relationship (tutors have subjects). I use the exact same code on another table but for some reason this code gives an error  which says the colum doesnt exist when it does.

> Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Subjects.subject_id' in 'on clause'

```
$tid = 12;
$sub = $this->Subjects->find('list')->hydrate(true);

$sub->matching('Tutors', function ($q) use ($tid) { 
    return $q->where(['Tutors.id' =>$tid]);
});
```

**Model in tutors**

```
$this->belongsToMany('Subjects', [
   'foreignKey' => 'tutor_id',
   'targetForeignKey' => 'subject_id',
   'joinTable' => 'tutors_subjects'
]);
```

Comment: Try rename your table `tutors_subjects` as `subjects_tutors`


[Join tables, used in BelongsToMany relationships between models, should be named after the model tables they will join, arranged in alphabetical order (articles_tags rather than tags_articles)](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html)

Comment: subjects_tutors  works so that was the problem. There is no way I would have guessed this as this table is crated by default.

Comment: Please make your post the answer , this is a real tricky one you solved

Comment: That shouldn't be the problem. CakePHP has conventions, but they are largely not being forced, ie specifying non-conventional table names should absolutely be no problem. I'd rather suspect that the model cache hasn't been cleared after altering the schema of the table in question.

Comment: ndm- all i did was rename the table and the code now works. This seems to be a problem with cakephp3 that Jack found the solution. I didnt specify this table name either as it is created by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try rename your table `tutors_subjects` as `subjects_tutors`

> Join tables, used in BelongsToMany relationships between models,
>   should be named after the model tables they will join, arranged in
>   alphabetical order (articles_tags rather than tags_articles)

More Info [Model and Database Conventions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions)